# Really easy percentage % question?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

So I have an exam coming up. Just trying to calculate the bare minimum I need to pass (although I am aiming for much higher).

I need 40% to pass the subject.

So from a previous exam worth 30%, I already have 18% of my grade.

I have an exam coming up worth 70% of the entire subject. So, 40 - 18 = 22. This means I need around 22% to pass.

The exam is out of 100 marks.

My question is, how many marks would I need to get to achieve the 22% needed.

Does that make sense? Sorry :(

Comment: Try a [grade weight calculator](http://www.benegg.net/grade_calculator.html).

Comment: I'd say 32, but I might have misread the question, so I advise you to check.

Answer (score 0):

From the $30$%, you earned $18$%, that means, if that test had $100$ points, you earned $\frac{18}{30}*100=\frac35*100=60$ points.

From the rest $70$%, you need to earn $22$%, that means, if the test had $100$ points, you need to earn $\frac{22}{70}*100=31,42$, so around $32$ points should do.